# Read in a selected column from a csv to edit and write back to the same csv using data.table?

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have a really large CSV that is a normalized gene expression matrix for a huuuuuuge single cell RNAseq dataset, and I made the mistake of not changing the mouse gene names to the human equivalents.

This is an example of what the data should look like where I want to change the values from the gene column to the human equivalent.

```r
library(data.table)
x <- fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dbrookeUAB/shared_files/master/example.csv')
x

      gene cell_1   cell_2 cell_3   cell_4 cell_5 cell_6   cell_7 cell_8
  1: Gsk3b      0 1.334471      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  2: Fgfr1      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  3:  Cd8a      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  4: Aurkb      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  5:   Tub      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  6: Casp9      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  7:   Cd4      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  8:  Cd19      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 0.000000      0
  9: Itgam      0 0.875049      0 1.591288      0      0 0.000000      0
 10: Itgax      0 0.000000      0 0.000000      0      0 1.719341      0
        cell_9  cell_10
  1: 0.9982402 0.000000
  2: 0.0000000 0.000000
  3: 0.0000000 0.000000
  4: 0.0000000 0.000000
  5: 0.0000000 0.000000
  6: 0.0000000 0.000000
  7: 0.0000000 0.000000
  8: 0.0000000 0.000000
  9: 0.0000000 1.324255
 10: 0.9982402 0.000000
```

I know that you can read in a specific column with `data.table`, but I was wondering if there was a way to write a single column to replace the one from the original csv? It just seems that would be more efficient than reading in an entire dataset just to fix one column.

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas you have!

Comment: I don't think any of the "standard" CSV tools (`utils::write.csv`, `readr::write_csv`, `data.table::fwrite`, or `vroom::vroom_write`) support writing a *portion* of each line back. This would effectively be random-access to the file, and while `vroom` does index each row/column for the purposes of lazy-reading, I don't think that can be easily adapted for *replacing* data (consider when the replacement value is a different length ... efficiently "shifting" all remaining chars isn't as easy as one might think). It's best to write a new file (or shift to using a DBMS, perhaps just `RSQLite`).

Comment: That makes sense. I figured there had to be a technical limitation that I wasn't understanding. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's actually pretty generic: *"random-access of text files"* has its own challenges, and *"random-access replacement"* has many more. If you want to consider alternate formats, perhaps serialized data (`fst`, `feather`) support it (idk).

Comment: @r2evans even columnar data formats like parquet cannot do this https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/1545 (i can't speak for all data formats)

Comment: @MichaelChirico that's what I suspected. (I didn't want to speak for other formats experience or confidence.) Thanks

Comment: If it's a replacement that can be done with `sed`, the `-i` (in-place) option should work

Comment: Dewey, does @MichaelChirico's comment have merit for your case? If you aren't familiar with `sed`, I might be able to suggest something assuming you can dumb down the data (perhaps only 10 chars instead of 10M :-).

Comment: @r2evans Absolutely! Sorry I let question die a little it. Would you mind  adding that as an answer?

Comment: *"... assuming you can dumb down the data ..."* was my way of suggesting you provide a simplified sample of input data, and the intended output with that input. Sorry, I wasn't being intentionally indirect or vague :-)

Comment: @MichaelChirico You are a saint! Would you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: @r2evans I appreciate all the help I can get! I'll get right on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a translation from `gene` to `human` (gene). Forgive me for not knowing those off the top of my head ... so I'll just use some `LETTERS` for that.

(BTW: the fact that the gene is in the first column makes this much more feasible and robust.)

```r
genes <- unique(fread("example.csv", select = 1))[, human := LETTERS[seq_len(.N)]]
genes[]
#      gene human
#  1: Gsk3b     A
#  2: Fgfr1     B
#  3:  Cd8a     C
#  4: Aurkb     D
#  5:   Tub     E
#  6: Casp9     F
#  7:   Cd4     G
#  8:  Cd19     H
#  9: Itgam     I
# 10: Itgax     J
```

Since the source data doesn't have quotes, simple patterns should suffice. I'll assume none of the genes have spaces (which might encourage some CSV-editing tools to use quotes) or commas (requiring quotes). Typically, if *any* of the values in a column require quotes, then *all* of the values will be quoted, but that's just empirical on my part.

Assuming there are more than "a few" genes to transfer, it's likely better to put the translations into a file and tell `sed` to read commands from there.

```r
writeLines(genes[, sprintf("s/^%s,/%s,/", gene, human)], "gene_to_human.sed")
readLines("gene_to_human.sed", n = 3)
# [1] "s/^Gsk3b,/A,/" "s/^Fgfr1,/B,/" "s/^Cd8a,/C,/"
```

From here, it's just a system call to use `sed`. I'm doing this from R, but frankly it can just as easily be done from a command-line (`cmd.exe`, `bash`, whatever). There should be no compromise either way, so use whatever you're comfortable with.

```r
Sys.which("sed") # included in Rtools
#                               sed 
# "c:\\Rtools40\\usr\\bin\\sed.exe" 
system2("sed", c("-f", "gene_to_human.sed", "example.csv"), stdout = "example2.csv")
readLines("example.csv", n = 3)
# [1] "gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10"
# [2] "Gsk3b,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0"                   
# [3] "Fgfr1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"                                                  
readLines("example2.csv", n = 3)
# [1] "gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10"
# [2] "A,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0"                       
# [3] "B,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
```

This created a new file. If your drive space is tight and/or you feel daring and want to modify it truly in-place (overwriting the original), then add the `-i` argument to sed:

```r
readLines("example.csv", n = 3)
# [1] "gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10"
# [2] "Gsk3b,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0"                   
# [3] "Fgfr1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"                                                  
system2("sed", c("-i", "-f", "gene_to_human.sed", "example.csv"))
readLines("example.csv", n = 3)
# [1] "gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10"
# [2] "A,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0"                       
# [3] "B,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
```

though until you're happy/comfortable with things, I think keeping the original file around is likely "A Good Thing (tm)".

---

### `bash` equivalents

(Assuming that you've created `"gene_to_human.sed"`.)

```bash
$ curl -s -o example.csv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dbrookeUAB/shared_files/master/example.csv

$ sed -i -f gene_to_human.sed example2.csv

$ head -n 3 example.csv
gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10
Gsk3b,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0
Fgfr1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

$ head -n 3 example2.csv
gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10
A,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0
B,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

or if you need to split it:

```bash
$ split -l 5 gene_to_human.sed  gene_to_human_split.sed.

$ ll gene_to_human*
-rw-r--r-- 1 r2 197121 144 Jun 12 16:44 gene_to_human.sed
-rw-r--r-- 1 r2 197121  72 Jun 12 17:04 gene_to_human_split.sed.aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 r2 197121  72 Jun 12 17:04 gene_to_human_split.sed.ab

$ cp example.csv example3.csv

$ for sedf in gene_to_human_split.sed.* ; do
    sed -i -f "${sedf}" example3.csv
  done

$ head -n 3 example3.csv
gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10
A,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0
B,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

---

### `sed` primer

The sed command we're using is the `s/old/new/` format, where on the command-line,

```bash
$ echo "hello world" | sed -e 's/hell/h-e-hockeysticks/'
h-e-hockeystickso world
```

Multiple commands can be executed many ways, including:

```bash
$ echo "hello world, goodbye world" | sed -e 's/hell/quux/;s/good/bad/'
quuxo world, badbye world

$ echo "hello world, goodbye world" | sed -e 's/hell/quuz/' -e 's/good/bad/'
quuzo world, badbye world
```

These are all replacing the first instance, you can make it `g`lobal replacement:

```r
$ echo "hello world, goodbye world" | sed -e 's/world/globe/'
hello globe, goodbye world

$ echo "hello world, goodbye world" | sed -e 's/world/globe/g'
hello globe, goodbye globe
```

Lastly, if there are many many many translations to do, I don't know if `sed` is going to crack under pressure of too many commands. If so, this can absolutely be done piecemeal. For this example, I'll limit it to 5 at a time, though `sed` can handle *many* more than that:

```r
Sys.which("split")
#                               split 
# "c:\\Rtools40\\usr\\bin\\split.exe" 
file.copy("example.csv", "example3.csv")
# [1] FALSE
readLines("example3.csv", n = 3)
# [1] "gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10"
# [2] "Gsk3b,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0"                   
# [3] "Fgfr1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"                                                  
system2("split", c("-l", "5", "gene_to_human.sed", "gene_to_human_split.sed."))
sedfiles <- list.files(pattern = "gene.*\\.sed\\..*")
sedfiles
# [1] "gene_to_human_split.sed.aa" "gene_to_human_split.sed.ab"
for (sedfile in sedfiles) system2("sed", c("-i", "-f", sedfile, "example3.csv"))
readLines("example3.csv", n = 3)
# [1] "gene,cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4,cell_5,cell_6,cell_7,cell_8,cell_9,cell_10"
# [2] "A,0,1.33447078154433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.998240198583345,0"                       
# [3] "B,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
```